Change default action in Xfburn
Within Xfburn the default action is to eject a disc when the burn is complete. How would I change that default setting to not eject a disc when the burn is complete?
Current system is Xubuntu 24.04

Unfortunately the eject setting default cannot be changed.  Several other settings can be made in ~/.config/xfburn/settings.xml.
